# how to show a DIV only the first time a website is loaded

Tags: javascript, show-hide, tumblr

I keep running around in circles about a show/hide a DIV.

I have this website: http://fugados.tumblr.com. I have embedded a map between the header and the posts as an iframe.

I'm looking for a way (and I'm blocked about how to do it) to show the map only the first time you load the website. After the initial load, if you click in a post or a page, I want the map hidden, with a band/button/tab to press if you want to see/open the map.

The reason is that the map takes up a lot of space, and moves down the content too much. The first visit to the website it's ok to see that the map is there, but if you want to read the content of the website, the map in every page eats too much space.

Thank you!

Comment: you can consider using cookies.

Comment: I see you have jQuery 1.7.2 in your page so you could also tag jQuery in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the eseist way is to use Local storage.
Set it on first Load

```
localStorage.setItem('wasVisited', 1);
```

And then check if it exists

```
if (localStorage.wasVisidet !== undefined ) {/* hide map */}
```

Comment: localStorage isn't supported on older browsers. I think cookies are better choice.

Comment: You are right. But I'm believ it's time to stop support that dinasours http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage

Answer (score 1):

You should use cookies.
First time when the page loads check if there is cookie value i.e. "hide_map" set to true. If yes, then hide the map. If not then don't hide the map but set the cookie "hide_map" value to true. This way the next time the user loads the page the "hide_map" will be true and you will hide the map.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ID for the map.
Then use document.getElementById("mapid").style.display="none";

Answer (score 0):

In this page: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp it talks about your problem, you can tweek it instead of showing greetning, hide your map with simple jquery code $("#idofyourmap").hide();